# MIPS- Reading integers error

Tags: arrays, input, integer, mips

```
# Programming Project 2
# Noah Heath
# @02685972

.data # Data declaration
      # A+B -(C-D x E)

string1: .asciiz "Please enter an integer from range 0 to 32768: "
string2: .asciiz "Next integer: "
string3: .asciiz "Invalid input. Start over. "
userinput: .space 100
var6: .asciiz "The result of A+B -(C-D x E) is: "
.text

main:
    la $a0, string1 #load string one and print
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a1, userinput 
    li $t1, 5 #set temporary variable to 5
    li $t0, 0 #start of counter

input:  
    beq $t0, $t1, exit
    li $v0, 5 # read integer
    syscall
    blt $v0, $zero, input # if input is less than zero
    bgt $v0, 32768, input # if input is greater than 32768
    sw $v0, 0($a1)
    addiu $a1, $a1, 4

exit:
    la $t3, userinput # stores base address of user input array into $t3
    lw $t4, ($t3) # load first number
    lw $t5, 4($t3) # load second number
    lw $t6, 8($t3) # load third number
    lw $t7, 12($t3) # load fourth number
    lw $t8, 16($t3) # load fifth number
    add $s1, $t4, $t5 # adds 1 and 2 into $t0
    mult $t7, $t8 # multiplies 2 and 3
    mflo $s2 # retrieves from register
    sub $s3, $t6, $s2 # subtracts 7 from 6
    sub $s4, $s1, $s3 # subtracts 1 from 3
    move $a0, $s4 # moves result into a0

    li $v0, 1 # instruction to print result
    syscall # call operating system to perform operation

    li $v0, 10 # exit instruction
    syscall
```

I'm been trying to figure out the reason that my code isn't reading the user integers and storing. I'm sure everything is syntactically correct. Can someone help me understand if I'm using the registers wrong?

QTSpim says Exception occurred at PC = 0x00400060.

Then goes on to say unaligned address in store= 0x1001005b.

It goes on in increments of 4(I'm assuming because of the way the array is indexed.

Final Error message is
    Exception 5 [Address error in store] occurred and ignored

```
Exception 4 [Address error in inst/data fetch] occurred and ignored(repeats 4 times)
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that jumps back to `input` to read another number after the first one has been stored. And if there was you'd probably have an infinite loop since you don't seem to be incrementing `$t0`.

Comment: Those were things I had in the program but going back and editing it I haven't put them back in. My problem is that I get an error when I try to input the first number.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question about an error that you get from a tool/OS you need to include the exact error message in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the errors at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code that asks for user input.

I guess your problem is that you are trying to store what the user entered in a non-aligned address (the line that issues `sw $v0, 0($a1)` ).

You should add a directive `.align 2` before your `userinput` label, e.g.:

```
string3: .asciiz "Invalid input. Start over. "
.align 2
userinput: .space 100
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still new to MIPS and our instruction is kind of rushed right now due to time constraints. Can you explain to me why that fixes my issue?

Comment: @NoahHeath: It fixes your problem because **word** memory accesses in MIPS must be word-aligned. The assembler directive `.align 2` ensures that the next data in your example (`userinput`) is aligned at a word boundary.

Comment: Ahhh that actually makes a ton of sense now. Thanks a bunch.